# Converting Belge 1972 / Belgian Lambert 72 (EPSG:31370) coordinates to WGS 84 (EPSG:4326)

Tags: c, coordinates

I am trying to find a code that can convert Lambert72 coordinates to WGS84, so that I can get the same results as I get in this site, going to Menu APPs->Transform Coordinates.

https://mygeodata.cloud/cs2cs/

As an example I tried the following coordinates pair in this site, choosing on the left, the code 31370 (Lambert72) and on the right, WGS84.:
149334.41 167411

The result is:
4.35930680453; 50.817136997

For this result to work on Google Maps, the values must be switched, so the result I need is rather:
50.817136997; 4.35930680453

I tried the code from this answer in a similar post but I converted to C instead of C++/C#:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40589076/1911497

So, my code, modified to C is this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

static void Lambert72toWGS84latlong(double X, double Y);

int main(){
    double x, y;
    
    x = 149334.41, y = 167411.0;
    
    Lambert72toWGS84latlong(x, y);

    return 0;
}


 static void Lambert72toWGS84latlong(double X, double Y){
 double LongRef = 0.076042943;
 double nLamb = 0.7716421928;
 double aCarre = pow(6378388.0,2.0);
 double bLamb  = 6378388.0 * (1.0 - (1.0 / 297.0));
 double eCarre = (aCarre - pow(bLamb,  2.0)) / aCarre;
 double KLamb = 11565915.812935;

 double eLamb = sqrt(eCarre);
 double eSur2 = eLamb / 2.0;

 double Tan1 = (X - 150000.012) / (5400088.437 - Y);
 double Lambda = LongRef + (1.0 / nLamb) * (0.000142043 + atan(Tan1));
 double RLamb = sqrt(pow((X - 150000.012) , 2.0) + pow   ((5400088.437 - Y) ,2.0));

 double TanZDemi = pow((RLamb / KLamb),(1.0 / nLamb));
 double Lati1 = 2.0 * atan(TanZDemi);

 double eSin;
 double Mult1, Mult2, Mult;
 double LatiN, Diff;

 double lat, lng ;
 int i=0; 
 do{
   eSin = eLamb * sin(Lati1);
   Mult1 = 1.0 - eSin;
   Mult2 = 1.0 + eSin;
   Mult = pow((Mult1 / Mult2) , (eLamb / 2.0));
   LatiN = (M_PI / 2.0) - (2.0 * (atan(TanZDemi * Mult)));
   Diff = LatiN - Lati1;
   printf("Diff: %d\n", abs(Diff));
   //Lati1 = LatiN;
   printf("Iterations: %d\n", i++);
  }while (abs(Diff)> 0.0000000277777);


  lat=LatiN;
  lng=Lambda;

  double SinLat = sin(lat);
  double SinLng = sin(lng);
  double CoSinLat = cos(lat);
  double CoSinLng = cos(lng);

  double dx = -125.8;
  double dy = 79.9;
  double dz = -100.5;
  double da = -251.0;
  double df = -0.000014192702;

  double LWf = 1.0 / 297.0;
  double LWa = 6378388.0;
  double LWb = (1 - LWf) * LWa;
  double LWe2 = (2.0 * LWf) - (LWf * LWf);
  double Adb = 1.0 / (1.0 - LWf);

  double Rn = LWa / sqrt(1.0 - LWe2 * SinLat * SinLat);    
  double Rm = LWa * (1 - LWe2) /pow((1.0 - LWe2 * lat * lat) ,1.5); 
  double DLat = -dx * SinLat * CoSinLng - dy * SinLat * SinLng + dz * CoSinLat;
  DLat = DLat + da * (Rn * LWe2 * SinLat * CoSinLat) / LWa;
  DLat = DLat + df * (Rm * Adb + Rn / Adb) * SinLat * CoSinLat;
  DLat = DLat / (Rm + 0.0);

  double DLng = (-dx * SinLng + dy * CoSinLng) / ((Rn + 0.0) * CoSinLat);
  double Dh = dx * CoSinLat * CoSinLng + dy * CoSinLat * SinLng + dz * SinLat;
  Dh = Dh - da * LWa / Rn + df * Rn * lat * lat / Adb;

  double LatWGS84 = ((lat + DLat) * 180.0) / M_PI;
  double LngWGS84 = ((lng + DLng) * 180.0) / M_PI;

  printf("Latitude: %.8f\t Longitude: %.8f\n", LatWGS84, LngWGS84);
}
```

However I don't get the same result.
The results I get are:
**Latitude: 50.78274764    Longitude: 4.35930689**

What would I need to change to be able to get the same result as the one returned by the mentioned site above?

Thanks
PsySc0rpi0n

Comment: *How* is the result different?

Comment: Sorry, will edit the original post and will add the result from that function. thanks Psy

Comment: Why did you comment out `Lati1 = LatiN;` (in the `do` loop)?

Comment: That was me just testing what would be the difference without that line, because if you don't comment that line, the while loop won't ever run more than once, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Try uncommenting it *and* using `fabs`.

Comment: I did that, I replied in comments in the answer below. It's close but still not exactly the same. Tiny differences here makes quite some difference.
This is the difference in the map:
https://i.ibb.co/nsSMsL0/imagem.png

Comment: *play with* `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28851350/same-flt-eval-method-different-results-in-gcc-clang ... but I'm inclined to say there's not enough error propagation to matter.

Comment: Have you verified that the original C++ produces the correct result?  If it doesn't, your translation doesn't have much of a chance.

Comment: What's the point of `Rm + 0.0` an later `Rn + 0.0`? Are those typos or the original code required some type conversions?

Comment: @pmg I will see what that constant means and I'll try to play with it to see if result changes.

Comment: @ScottHunter I didn't try the original code because I'm not confortable with c++. That's why I did the transaltion to C. Anyway, the only difference from one code to the other is in 2 functions and a constant. Math.Abs to fabs(), Math.Pow to pow() and Math.PI to M_PI. These were the only things I changed.

Comment: @Bob__ That's in the original code. I'm not familiar with the steps to convert from one system of coordinates to the other, so I just used the original code as is, except from the transalation.

Comment: Also, maybe try making `long double` variables (and operations... remember `sqrtl()`, `fabsl()`, `powl()`, ...) in your translated code. I don't have a C# compiler/debugger... would be fun to statement-by-statement debug both versions side-by-side :-)

Comment: On my computer (where `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` is `0`) your code gives the wanted result (in 3 iterations) with `//Lati1 = LatiN;` uncommented and using `fabs()`.

Comment: Also works on godbolt... https://godbolt.org/z/W9vPYav9G

Comment: @pmg: I don't think "fun" means what you think means. :)

Comment: @pmg I'll try to change the functions to those you mention. I was also using an online C compiler, so I'm not sure I can change the FLT_EVAL_METHOD const variable in the code or if it's an OS env variable which I would need (if i'm not mistaken) access to a shell to be able to change it.

Comment: @pmg I tried with compiler flag `-mfpmath=387`, which I think it is equivalent to `FLT_EVAL_METHOD 2` and with the sqrtl(), powl() and fabsl() functions The result is still not the one I need. I get: **Latitude: 50.81742339    Longitude: 4.35956292**

Comment: @pmg for the input coordintes  x =149334.41, y = 167411.0 you get **Latitude: 50.81713876  Longitude: 4.35930782** but I need them to be **50.817136997, 4.35930680453**.
Sorry if I already mess up with the input and output values. I think, in the meantime, I tried other input values and was replying above for those new values.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> do {
>     // stuff
> } while (abs(Diff)> 0.0000000277777);
> //     **int abs(int);**
> ```

You probably want

```
 do {
     // stuff
 } while (fabs(Diff) > 0.0000000277777);
 //     **double fabs(double);**
```

Comment: That is a necessary, but not sufficient, fix.

Comment: The original code is Math.Abs(). I just used what was in the original code but converted to C. Will try though and will report back.

Comment: [C#'s `Math.Abs()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.abs?view=net-5.0) is different than [C's `abs()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/abs.html)

Comment: Ok, with fabs() it's closer but still not good enough to what I need.
I get:

Latitude: 50.81713876    Longitude: 4.35930782

@pmg ok I didn't know that. Thanks